# React loadable-components with Parcel Bundler

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, parceljs

I still get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: loadable-components: modules
>   entry is missing, you are probably missing `loadable-components/babel`
>   in your Babel config.

Although my `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
    "plugins": ["loadable-components/babel"]
}
```

Any Ideas/Mistakes?

Comment: Its `"plugins": ["@loadable/babel-plugin"],`